# localVarFormParams.getHeaders is not function when using openai.createImageEdit()

Tags: react-native, openai-api

this is my function

```
const generatedDalleImage = async () => {
    
    await openai.createImageEdit(
      selectedImage,
      selectedMaskImage,
      "human face",
      1,
      "1024x1024"
    ).then((response) => {
      console.log(response); 
      setGeneratedImage(response.data.data[0].url)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });


  }
```

i am getting this error
localVarFormParams.getHeaders is not function when using openai.createImageEdit()

i am really stuck in this one so any help is appreciated